# protect API endpoints using the keycloak groups with spring webflux

Tags: kotlin, keycloak, openid-connect, spring-webflux

I am creating an API server with spring webflux.

I understand that `SecurityWebFilterChain` can protect API endpoints as follows:

```kotlin
@EnableWebFluxSecurity
@EnableReactiveMethodSecurity
@Configuration
open class SecurityConfig : WebFluxConfigurer {
    @Bean
    fun security(http: ServerHttpSecurity): SecurityWebFilterChain =
        http
            .httpBasic().disable()
            .formLogin().disable()
            .logout().disable()
            .csrf().disable()
            .authorizeExchange()
            .anyExchange().authenticated()
            .and()
            .oauth2ResourceServer()
            .jwt()
            .and().and()
            .build()
```

limit the role, I think it will be as follows.

```
authorizeExchange()
    .pathMatchers("/admin/**")
    .hasRole("admin")
```

Is there a way to use keycloak groups in a similar way?

example:

```
authorizeExchange()
    .pathMatchers("/admin/**")
    .hasGroup("admin")
```

If not possible, Is there another way?

I tried `keycloak-spring-security-adapter` but it didn't seem to work with spring webflux.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally that is possible.

### Check which authorities are present

For example by adding an `Authentication` parameter to your RestController and call `getAuthorities()` to aquire a list of all grated authorities. In this context roles are prefixed with `ROLE_`

### Groups are present?

Just use `hasRole()`

### Groups are not present?

Look out for the used implementation of `UserDetailsService`, as you have to extend it to add your groups.

### Adding hasGroups

Here is an extenson function to do that

```
fun ServerHttpSecurity.AuthorizeExchangeSpec.Access.hasGroup(group: String) =
  access(AuthorityReactiveAuthorizationManager.hasAuthority("GROUP_$group"))
```

Comment: thank you for answering. It seems to work. However, software specification that I think could not be realized. I asked the question again. Please help me if you like. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63090888/allow-or-deny-login-by-keycloak-groups-when-logging-in